# Some transparent images on labels have black backgrounds when using PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, png, python-3.9

I have a frame where I put multiple labels on. All of these labels contain png images, some that fill the whole background, and others that don't; have transparent backgrounds. I want to get 16x16 px images and resize them to 32x32 for visibility. I noticed that the original images work fine when resized, but when I add a new image to the assets directory and use it, its background turns black.
I have an assets folder where I store my png images. I am sure that every one of them should have transparent backgrounds, atleast according to my photo editor.

This is the minimal code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
project_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
root = Tk()

button_frame1 = Frame(root)
button_frame1.pack(side=TOP)
Label(button_frame1, text="Hotbar",padx=8).grid(row=0,column=2)
hotbarFrame = Frame(button_frame1, bg="white", width=288, height=32, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
hotbarFrame.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=10)
hotbarItems = ["dirt", "grass_block_side", "grass", "stone", "cobblestone", "oak_planks", "oak_log", "oak_leaves2", "glass"]
hotbarImages, hotbarSlots = {}, []

for slot in range(len(hotbarItems)):
    item = hotbarItems[slot]
    item_file = open(project_path + "\\assets\\blocks\\" + item + ".png", "rb")
    hotbarImages[item] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(item_file).resize((32,32), Image.NONE))
    hotbarSlots.append(Label(hotbarFrame, image=hotbarImages[item], width=32, height=32, highlightthickness=1))
    hotbarSlots[slot].grid(row=0,column=slot)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:
[Notice that the eighth icon has a black background, even though it's transparent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbWPi.png)

[Click here to see the original eighth icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnKvY.png)

Comment: It may be because the image is not in "RGBA" mode.  Try converting it to "RGBA" mode: `Image.open(item_file).resize((32,32), Image.NONE).convert("RGBA")`.

Comment: that works on my actual script. (somehow on another script it didn't work, which is weird.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your PNG image not in RGBA mode, but in P mode.

> P mode
> 8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a color palette

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("D:/oak_leaves2.png")
print(im.mode)        # P
im.show()
```

Following simple script show the result

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='blue')
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

im = Image.open("D:/oak_leaves2.png").resize((80, 80), Image.BICUBIC)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

label = tk.Label(frame, text='Hello', image=image)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So, actually, it look like this

[image]

Comment: This worked when I chose "RGBA" mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  this code

```
    hotbarSlots.append(Label(hotbarFrame, image=hotbarImages[item], width=32, height=32, highlightthickness=1 , bd=None))
```

or can put same as color of that label same of window'sbackground

```
root.config(bg="white")
hotbarSlots.append(Label(hotbarFrame, image=hotbarImages[item], width=32,height=32, highlightthickness=1 , background="white"))
```

Comment: Option 1 (using "bd=None") did not work for me and neither did Option 2. It looks the same as the output I sent before.

Comment: so you need to  bd=None  for Frame

Comment: why `None` and not `0`?

Comment: @NadeemAli that still doesn't do anything ("bd=None" and even "bd=0").

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).